# Number of distinct not-permuted positive-integer-valued solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + ... + x_k = N$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Is there any general formula to find the number of distinct set of not-permuted positive integers which satisfy the following equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + .. + x_k = N$$ where $N$ is a positive integer greater than $k$.

By distinct not-permuted, I mean the following:
Say, if we take the equation $$x_1+ x_2 + x_3 = 5$$
Then, the possible solutions are {(1,1,3), (1,3,1), (3,1,1), (1,2,2), (2,1,2), (2,2,1)}
and the distinct not-permuted solutions are: {(1,1,3), (1,2,2)} i.e. number of distinct solutions are 2 in this case.

I would really appreciate any help and/or suggestion towards the solution.

Comment: [The restricted partition number $p_k(N)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).  There is not a clean formula.  [Some calculators](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partition+15+into+5+parts) can handle this.